# what is wrong about the layout in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

i installed Android Studio but in the video there was a phone[enter image description here here's the difference, mine:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBm37.png)

[and his screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7jAM.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the Design view instead of the Text view. You would want to look to the lower left of the coding window and select Design:

[image]